# how to restore tmux last application

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

I have been using tmux for a while. one thing is very annoying me is that there is a way to restore last time application. for example:

in my current tmux session, I have three windows (two running in horizontal window, and one running as vertical window). I want to have a way to save this settings or this session, and restore it back in later.

the solution I tried is use bash alias command, which is not very helpful. (basically you still need to manually type all the command, spliting windows, and adjusting windows) I want a very lazy way to do this, as much you can get(just one command does all the job will be great)

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is a way to declare sessions in you `~/.tmux.conf`, as you specifically mention layouts you will want [tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator)